# I have a single socket and I would like to know if I can run four more from it

Tags: kitchens

Can I add four more sockets from a single socket

Answer (score 2):

No problem, just parallel them.   Hot to hot, neutral to neutral, ground to ground, etc.  Use wire nuts and pigtails when you have to attach more than 2 wires to a receptacle side.